# how to take the content of a file as a String in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am finding some difficulties to do the following operation in Java:

I have to take the content of an xml file and print it

I do something like this:

```
System.out.println("settings.xml: " + ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/home/andrea/Documenti/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/src/settings.xml"));
```

The problem is that the result of this statment is:

```
settings.xml: null
```

Why? What can I do to do it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of `getResourceAsStream`? Is `/home/andrea/Documenti/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/src/settings.xml` on the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
private String getStringFromFile(File file)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
System.out.println("settings.xml: " + ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("home/andrea/Documenti/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/src/settings.xml"));
```